# How do Update Qt Scene Graph from c++?

Tags: qt, opengl, qtquick2, scenegraph

I wrote a c++ `QQuickItem` component for drawing curve, but for updating the curve, i have to call update method by a timer.

example  of what i am doing:

```
Item {
    Curve {
        id: curve
        height: 100
        width: 600
    }

Timer {
    id: timer
    interval:20
    repeat: true
    running: true
    onTriggered: {
        curve.update()
    }
 }
}
```

Is there any way to call it from C++?

Answer (score 0):

The function you seek is:

[`void QQuickWindow::update()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#update)

> Schedules the window to render another frame.
>
> Calling QQuickWindow::update() differs from QQuickItem::update() in
>   that it always triggers a repaint, regardless of changes in the
>   underlying scene graph or not.

You can get access to the underlying window from any `QQuickItem`, for example `someItem->window()->update()`, or you can pass the `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` directly.

[You will have to implement a basic `QObject` derived accessor object so you can invoke the C++ function from QML, passing it a QML object as a parameter, either a window or item. Then create an instance in `main.cpp`, expose it as a context property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html), then from QML you can simply `onTriggered: Accessor.requestUpdate(someItem/someWindow)`

Comment: Can you clarify it by an example?

Comment: it says Updates can only be scheduled from GUI thread or from QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()

Comment: @sayyedmohsenzahraee - in that case try invoking the function with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` with `Qt::QueuedConnection`.